# How to ignore errors while executing a bulk insertion in Pymongo. I am using ordered bulk write operation in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to bulk insert some documents in a mongodb collection.

I have imposed a unique constraint on **link** field of my collection.

```
bulkUrls = db.urls.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()

for info in links:
    info = urljoin(url['link'], info)
    if '#' in info:
        info = info[:info.index('#')]
        if(validateUrl(info)):
            bulkUrls.insert({'link' : info, 'last_processed' : 0,     'created_at' : time(), 'page_id' : str(inserted_id), 'opened' : False})
bulkUrls.execute()
```

attached is my python code.
I want to insert the document only when there is no other document already present in the collection with the same `link` field.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have to use ordered bulk, you can use unordered bulk operation instead.

Unordered bulk write operations are batched and sent to the server in arbitrary order where they may be executed in parallel. Any errors that occur are reported after all operations are attempted.
from [pymongo documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.7rc0/examples/bulk.html)

So simply use:

```
bulkUrls = db.urls.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
```

If you insist to use ordered bulk, you may set the write concern to 0.

according to the same link above,

```
bulkUrls.execute({'w': 0})
```

Note: This will disables write acknowledgement, which means you will not know if the write operation succeeded or not ("Not Recommended").

Comment: Thanx ... using unordered solved my problem. I hadn't checked the documentation completely before... my bad. Thanx!